# Network driver for Realtek 8852 20.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek, lan

I recently bought a new HP laptop (Pavilion 15-ec2003np), but when I installed ubuntu (already tried 20.04, 20.10, Pop!_OS 20.04, 20.10) it says that the network adapter wasn't found and I can only have internet via cable.
Already searched for the drivers but I cant seem to find the correct one.
The laptop has a Realtek 8852 network adapter.

Has anyone else had the same issue?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04 and ran some commands to get some info.
Also, i went through the network troubleshoot from the ubuntu website (only thing i didnt try from there was using the windows drivers) but still no success.
Here are the results of the following commands:

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:56c9 IMC Networks HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:2852 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

nmcli device:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
eno1    ethernet  unavailable  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

lshw -C network:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: b0:22:7a:d7:6a:07
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:34 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc904000-fc904fff memory:fc900000-fc903fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc8fffff
```

lspci -nn:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex [1022:1630]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU [1022:1631]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1633]
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
00:08.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166a]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166b]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166c]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166d]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166e]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166f]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1670]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1671]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [10de:1f99] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5405]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [1002:1638] (rev c5)
05:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
05:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
05:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
05:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
06:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 81)
06:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 81)
```

Comment: Pop OS is not on-topic here as only Ubuntu and *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu are on-topic (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as uses *testing* grade software, non-Ubuntu kernels & software.  Ubuntu LTS releases have two software stack choices (which can be changed post-install, but are selected by ISO used to install) and you were not specific on which you tried.. nor if you tried the network troubleshooting guide

Comment: If you're currently using a supported version of Ubuntu, could you update your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb`? There are a couple of different variations of the `RTL8852`.

Comment: Added the outputs from multiple commands.
@guiverc im not sure what you mean by software stack. I've used the ubuntu 21.04 iso downloaded from here: https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.04/ (desktop image) and proceeded to the installation.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases offer two software stacks (GA or the general stack remains the same the entire life of the product), or HWE (hardware enablement which moves to later stacks following non-LTS releases allowing later kernel modules (drivers) for newer devices..) Your mention of the off-topic (which uses *testing* stack as well) means I don't know what you have sorry. (21.04 doesn't have stack choices; it's kernel & stack gets used by 20.04 using HWE stack, but it wasn't mentioned in your question; unclear)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED or FIXED in the question title. This is a question answer site. You are most welcome to answer your own question by clicking on the **Answer My Own Question** button. Then after the waiting period accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray ✔️ mark and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Comment: @user68186 My bad, already edited and did what you mentioned. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it fixed.
In case anyone else has the same problem, all i did was follow the guide in this github repo: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 I had already done that before but i was using the rtw88 instead of rtw89 (which was the one i needed).

Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Hi @rfdomingues98 , could you post the steps you followed? I am unsure about the part of "If it turns out that your system needs one of the configuration options, then do the following:" THANKS

Comment: I answer myself, just doing the 'For all distros:' block of code followed by reboot worked on pop os 20.04.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I got it fixed by following the instructions from requirements to the kernel module part

Comment: This saved my day, thank you

Comment: Oh my god! Thankyou so much! This works like a charm!

Comment: worked on Lenovo Thinkpad P14s Gen1 :)