# After Ubuntu 20.04 suspends, the USB's does not work

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, usb, suspend

After waking up from suspend ubuntu no longer detects any usb. I have to restart everytime my system wakes from suspend so that the USB mouse and keyboard work.

System information:

HP Pavilion 15-ec2008AX

Processor: AMD® Ryzen 5 5600h with radeon graphics

Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation / AMD® Renoir

I had to manually install the realtek wifi drivers.
Link - [Realtek RTL8852AE issue on Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6 (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344184/realtek-rtl8852ae-issue-on-lenovo-legion-5-pro-16ach6-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I am confused how does the manually install WiFi driver have to do with the missing USB on wake from suspend?

Comment: The wifi driver has nothing do with USB wake action. I mentioned it only because users who had wifi driver issue might have had the same issue and would get their attention.