# My wifi card is not detected on Realtek RTS522A Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless

My wifi card is not detected on Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device a85a Ubuntu 20.04.3. I have tried all kinds of different threads that have a similar problem and nothing has worked. I get the following message:

0000:02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device a85a

A teacher told me he thinks the "blob" is missing but I don't know what that means.

Here are some commands I have tried:

```
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw89pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-43-generic***
```

Is there something I can do to solve it? I've been trying to solve
this problem for 2 months now and I'm a bit desperate.

THANK YOU FOR THE HELP

****INFO****

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:a85a]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e2]
10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)


sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:52000000-520fff
```

I'm getting this by following the thread that @chili555 suggested:

[changed everything to documents folder and I'm getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqjk5.png)

Comment: "sudo dkms install rts_pstor" What exactly is rts_pstor? Please edit your question and show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: And "Realtek RTS522A" is a card reader. And #2 install Broadcom drivers???

Comment: Please confirm that it is your *wireless* card that you are trying to get working. I will then edit your question to streamline it to remove non-essential data.

Comment: I think it's called the wireless card. When I start the system there are no wifi networks I can connect to. The network symbol does not even appear unless I connect by cable.

Comment: The problem is that the computer came with windows installed, and it seems the wifi drivers are not compatible with linux

Comment: Do yu have an rtw89pci folder on your computer? How/where did you get: `sudo modprobe rtw89pci`?

Comment: I followed this thread because it is the same problem but with a different model:          https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344184/realtek-rtl8852ae-issue-on-lenovo-legion-5-pro-16ach6-ubuntu-20-04/1344194#1344194

Comment: It appears then that you did not properly build the driver. I shall propose an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the correct driver for your device is indeed rtw89pci. Let's start from the beginning. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential bc
```

Next, follow this process exactly: [How to get Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi card to work on my new laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379716/how-to-get-realtek-rtl8852ae-wifi-card-to-work-on-my-new-laptop/1379800#1379800)

If applicable, you will have to disable Secure Boot.

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I edited the post uploading two pictures of what I'm getting when I follow the process you shared. Is it because I need to disable secure boot before doing that? Thank you for your help

Comment: You are in the wrong directory! Your prompt says you are in the root directory /. Please do: `cd ~` and try again. The ~ is on the upper left of my US keyboard. The root directory / is not writable by us mere mortal humans!

Comment: hahaha true, changed it to the documents folder and I'm getting: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted

Comment: `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` but first turn off Secure Boot.

Comment: It is fixed!!!! Thank you soooo much

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!