# Wifi not working with Kubuntu 21.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad L15 Gen2 AMD

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, lenovo

Since Lenovo last year, 2020 summer, announced that they officially support Ubuntu with many of their models I dared to buy Lenovo Thinkpad L15 Gen2 AMD with the hope that I will avoid exactly this situation... However unluckily the wifi adapter is not working... :( Do you have tipps for me? Thank you!

https://news.lenovo.com/pressroom/press-releases/lenovo-launches-linux-ready-thinkpad-and-thinkstation-pcs-preinstalled-with-ubuntu/

https://ubuntu.com/certified/202103-28879

What I have already tried:
live-isos from following distros:

- Kubuntu kubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64
- Manjaro manjaro-kde-21.0.7-210614-linux510.iso
- Pop OS pop-os_21.04_amd64_intel_6.iso

-> non of them support the wifi HW

After installing Kubuntu 21.04 i can print the following infos:

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 38:f3:ab:ea:74:ba
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.182 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd704000-fd704fff memory:fd700000-fd703fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd600000-fd6fffff


rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT 07.18.2021:

```
sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166a
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166b
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166c
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166d
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166e
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166f
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1670
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1671
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
06:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c2)
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lspci`? This may contain enough details about the wireless device’s hardware to offer a solution 

Comment: edit done. Thank you for the hint. The problem looks also solved for after finding this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336379/network-driver-for-realtek-8852-20-10

Comment: Issue solved with (*)Ubuntu 22.04 LTS