# Ubuntu 20.04 No Wifi Adapter Found. Lenovo Ideapad Realtek

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I bought a new Lenovo Ideapad 5 without any OS. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. However, in Settings -> Wi-Fi I see "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I already spent hours trying to solve this problem. I don't know, what I'm missing.

Here, I paste the output from some common commands I found.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d05fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 16:00:4c:38:bb:e6
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.59 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
lspci -v | grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
```

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:4852 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4d Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS motorola one vision
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b725 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also, in Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers there is "No additional drivers available"

I have no idea, what to do next. Please, help.

Comment: Check secure boot in bios. Is it off?

Comment: Secure boot was enabled. I just changed it to disabled. Should anything be changed now?

Comment: That is your problem.

Comment: Should I install Ubuntu again?

Comment: If it isn't up yet, that would be your best bet... or you could try to upgrade kernel.

Comment: Try hard reboot once more. If that doesn't work, ensure that you hit save changes before leaving. Ive made that mistake before.

Comment: What is the second network under lshw? Ubuntu doesn't have a driver available for the Realtek 8852. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek#PCI). You still may be able to get it working with a windows driver and ndiswrapper. Actually, I think I found a solution. Changing answer.

Comment: Here is a verified working solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-wifi-6-ax200-on-ubuntu-21-04/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the realtek 8852 PCI adapter working with Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. Download dependencies:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
   ```
2. Install 'fix':

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
   cd rtw89 && make && sudo make install
   ```
3. load module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtw89pci
   ```

   If you are lucky, this is all you will need to do. The driver should be loaded. If not, you will likely know. The driver load attempt will have caused an error. If this is the case, click the source link below for details.

---

[Source & src](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#installation-instruction)

[Another Ubuntu user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336379/network-driver-for-realtek-8852-20-10) who used method with success (rtw89)

Comment: Thank you. I installed Ubuntu today, so I'm not losing anything. I'll try to install this again with disabled Secure Boot and I hope this will solve my problems

Comment: I know it will. It is a common issue. Secure boot looks for windows signature to decide if an app is secure. Other distros such as RHEL have gone as far as to dupe the software signatures. Ubuntu just provides you with the info to [do it yourself](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) if needed. The easier option is just to say good riddance.

Comment: So I disabled Secure Boot and installed Ubuntu again. I still have the same problems. Basically, nothing changed from the previous output

Comment: @NateT I believe OP will require firmware.

Comment: Thank you again, @NateT. How did you know I needed rtw89pci? I couldn't find this information

Comment: I was searching around when I came across the second link in the answer. The op was having the same issue as you, and I noticed he gotten it fixed by installing. I followed the link and read the info. Imo a user's success with Ubuntu (and Linux in general)  depends mostly on how effective his or her googling skills are. XD

Comment: Thanks. This helped me, it did the job. I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a Lenovo Thinkpad G4