# Ubuntu 20.04 No wifi adapter found Lenovo G5

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I bought a new laptop (Lenovo legion G5) I installed windows & ubuntu in dual boot.
On windows side my wireless adapter work as well, but on Ubuntu I got this message : No wifi adapter found.

I tried many solutions, I found [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352731/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-lenovo-ideapad-realtek?newreg=1f757035426044a7ad20fad87520d861) wich is very similar to my laptop specs, but unfortunately when I execute this command :

```
cd rtw89 && make && sudo make install
```

I got an error message :

```
cp: cannot stat 'rtl8852au*.bin': No such file or directory
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 15
   serial: 90:2e:16:35:2a:ee
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1704000-d1704fff memory:d1700000-d1703fff

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1600000-d16fffff
```

lspci -v | grep -i network

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
```

[Result of dmesg -t](https://pastebin.com/07ppsJF1)

Answer (score 0):

Please add these steps to your process and report the result:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Invalid argument
I added the result of dmesg -t command in my post

Comment: Ah, haa! You have a probably conflicting driver loaded. Please do: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`, reboot and show me a new dmesg.

Comment: Result [here](https://pastebin.com/n3yfSVdc)
Got same result from sudo modprobe rtw89pci command

Comment: With the ethernet connected, try: `cd rtw89` and: `make clean` and: `git pull` and: `make` finally: `sudo make install` Any improvement after a reboot? Reference: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/issues/76

Comment: I have followed your steps : [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2464841&p=14048367#post14048367). Now when I `sudo make install` I have this message `Install rtw89 SUCCESS` After a reboot my wifi still does not work. Command `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` return this error message `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Invalid argument`

Comment: [Result](https://pastebin.com/yLQKeSfQ) of `sudo dmesg | grep rtw`