# How to get Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi card to work on my new laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I bought a new Lenovo Ideapad 5 Pro that ships with this network card, full name:

> Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter

Ubuntu (or any other linux distribution) does not recognize or provide drivers for this wireless card. Please tell me if there is a viable solution to this problem, or I will have to wait for an unknown amount of time until the driver is provided.

I already searched through askubuntu and found this [Network driver for Realtek 8852 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336379/network-driver-for-realtek-8852-20-10)

but the guide is very hard for me to understand, they use an unofficial driver from a kind git user, and say that I will need to rebuild it every time my system gets updated. Another big concern for me is, even if I were to do all this, how can I get it installed in the first place? The driver itself requires some packages that I would need to install first, which I cannot do without internet connection. My laptop does not have an ethernet port, only wireless card that does not work. I am desperate to make Linux work on my main machine and I don't want to give up.

Comment: I understand it looks daunting, but it is pretty easy and we can guide you. Can you tether your phone? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Help is greatly appreciated. I found an option on my android phone that says "Ethernet tethering - Share phone's internet connection via USB ethernet." so I assume yes, I can.

Comment: Tip: Make sure your phone is connected to WiFi before connecting the cable and enabling the tethering option so you don't spend your (mobile) data plan.

Comment: Please tether your phone and do: `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install git build-essential linux-headers-generic` Are there any errors? If not, I will propose a step-by-step answer.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: @chili555 done! No errors :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you have installed the prerequisites successfully by tethering, let's install the driver. It can all be done from the terminal!

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Your wireless should now be working.

When Update Manager offers and installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, you must rebuild the driver:

```
cd rtw89
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Please retain the rtw89pci directory and these instructions for that time.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. Have fun!

Comment: If you get the error `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted` then you will have to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI, and try the `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` again.

Comment: The instructions now say to use `sudo make sign-install` to use with secure boot.

Comment: Worked beautifully after a restart. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the simplest and most elegant solution to this problem (and Ethernet issues for some other Lenovo models, like the P14s Gen2) if you are running 20.04 seems to be:
`sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04d`

Comment: Is there any documentation to support your answer?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/issues/75

Comment: @pzegadlo Thank you very much!
had the same problem with Wi-Fi, oem kernel version helped