# Network Driver for Realtek 10ec:b852

Tags: drivers, realtek

My laptop says "No WiFi adapter found" when I go to settings.  Here is what lpsi returns:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
```

and `lshw -C network`:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:80500000-805fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enxeaa730017396
       serial: ea:a7:30:01:73:96
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth driverversion=5.15.0-35-generic ip=172.20.10.8 link=yes multicast=yes
```

`lsmod | grep rtw` results:

```
rtw89pci               49152  0
rtw89core             352256  1 rtw89pci
mac80211             1228800  2 rtw89pci,rtw89core
cfg80211              958464  2 rtw89core,mac80211
```

`modinfo rtw89pci` results:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/rtw89pci.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Realtek 802.11ax wireless PCI driver
author:         Realtek Corporation
srcversion:     5F18D2B3333DF111288DB86
depends:        rtw89core,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           rtw89pci
vermagic:       5.15.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           disable_clkreq:Set Y to disable PCI clkreq support (bool)
parm:           disable_aspm_l1:Set Y to disable PCI ASPM L1 support (bool)
parm:           disable_aspm_l1ss:Set Y to disable PCI L1SS support (bool)
```

I have checked that it is not hard-blocked in BIOS. I have tried both the rtw89 and rtw88 drivers and followed instructions for those to no avail.  I also tried buying a wifi usb dongle, but cannot get that one to work with linux either.

I have a Lenovo yoga 6 13ALC7 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  Is there any way to get wifi on this computer?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Which instructions did you use? Did you use [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379800/167115)? Also, if you are using secure boot, the instructions have changed and I believe you should use `sudo make sign-install` or you could use the regular instructions and disable secure boot.

Comment: Yes, I did follow that one, and just tried a clean and re-install.  It says successful but then I still have no wifi adapter after reboot.  When I ran `sudo make sign-install` I get the message:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'sign-install'.  Stop.`

Comment: More clearly, after a reboot, run `lsmod | grep rtw` and look for kernel modules like `rtw89`, if you see one listed (rtw89 for example), disable it: `sudo modprobe -r rtw89` and then load the built module: `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` If this works, let me know and I'll give a full answer below.

Comment: If no kernel modules are listed when you run `lsmod | grep rtw` then you can simply run `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` to load the built module. This should enable the wifi. Again, please let me know if this works and I will write a full answer below.

Comment: Yes rebooted several times to make sure.
When I run `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` it just goes to a new line, no error message.  Not sure if that means it was successful or not.  
Here are the results of `lsmod | grep rtw`

rtw89pci               49152  0
rtw89core             352256  1 rtw89pci
mac80211             1228800  2 rtw89pci,rtw89core
cfg80211              958464  2 rtw89core,mac80211

Do any of those need to be blacklisted?
(and that you so much for the quick help!)

Comment: ok, just rebooted again to be sure.  This time `lsmod | grep rtw` returned nothing.  So I ran `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` and got back: `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-35-generic`

Comment: Try the modprobe again. It looks like the command was not finished or it would return that Module rtw89pci was not found.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try running `sudo modprobe rtw89` to see if the default kernel works for you although, it should've worked from the beginning if this were the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Tried modprobe again and nothing happens.  Still not seeing the wifi adapter.  Every time I reboot and run lsmod it returns empty.  Then I re-run modprobe and it returns the rtw89pci items.  But it's still not seeing the adapter.  Tried `sudo modprobe rtw89` and it returned `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw89 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-35-generic`  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Kelli User Chilli just posted an alternate driver for your particular device. Reboot before you run the commands. [The answer is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412264/167115), just **skip the first two commands (start with `sudo apt update`)**. Also, after you run `sudo make install` you may need to run `sudo modprobe 8852be` to load the driver.

Comment: @mchid That worked!  Thank you!  If you'd like to put it as an answer instead of a comment I will mark it as answered by you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User @Chilli just posted an alternate driver for your particular device. Reboot before you run the commands. [The answer is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412264/167115), just **skip the first two commands (start with sudo `apt update`).** Also, after you run `sudo make install` you may need to run `sudo modprobe 8852be` to load the driver.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git bc
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```

Please view (and upvote) [the original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412264/167115) for more info and for instructions on how to recompile after a future kernel update.

Comment: @michael-nixon You should post the edit as an answer instead of an edit.

Answer (score 6):

The driver rtl8852be is obsolete, and generally inferior to the one now in https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git, which parallels the code that will be in kernel 6.2 when it is released in 2-3 months. The repo https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be.git will be deleted on Dec. 1.

Answer (score 1):

As [hinted by Larry Finger](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442959/682414), installing Linux **kernel 6.2** or newer solves this issue. By now, running the Software Updater should install a recent enough kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.