# WiFi not available on Lenovo Thinkpad / Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, thinkpad

I bought a new Laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad E15 Gen 4 21EE) and installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. The problem is that I can only access the internet via an ethernet cable, as there is no option for WiFi. I already spent hours searching for a solution and installed tons of packages, but I am not really experienced with Ubuntu and hardware/drivers in general and nothing worked. It would be really nice if someone could help me, because I really need the WiFi for my work.

Many thanks in advance,

Paul

**Edit 1:** The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]

04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo [1002:15e7] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:50b1]
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Edit 2:** The question was closed an redirected to a similar question ([Network Driver for Realtek 10ec:b852](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852)). I executed

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install git bc
    git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
    cd rtl8852be
    make
    sudo make install
    sudo modprobe 8852be
```

and the output was

```
    Hit:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
    Hit:2 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
    Hit:3 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
    Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    All packages are up to date.
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    bc is already the newest version (1.07.1-3build1).
    git is already the newest version (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.4).
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver
      intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58
      libavutil56 libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1
      libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1
      libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12 liblilv-0-0 libmfx1 libmysofa1
      libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2
      libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0
      libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0
      libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1
      libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
      mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers pocketsphinx-en-us va-driver-all
      vdpau-driver-all
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Cloning into 'rtl8852be'...
    remote: Enumerating objects: 1067, done.
    remote: Counting objects: 100% (1067/1067), done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (838/838), done.
    remote: Total 1067 (delta 271), reused 980 (delta 218), pack-reused 0
    Receiving objects: 100% (1067/1067), 4.34 MiB | 2.27 MiB/s, done.
    Resolving deltas: 100% (271/271), done.
    /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
    (standard_in) 1: syntax error
    #rm -f .symvers.8852be
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/build M=/home/paul/rtl8852be  modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48-generic'
    arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
    make[1]: gcc: No such file or directory
    warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
      The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
      You are using:           
    /bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
    (standard_in) 1: syntax error
      CC [M]  /home/paul/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o
    /bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
    make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297:                 /home/paul/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o] Error 127
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:1884: /home/paul/rtl8852be] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48-generic'
    make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Error 2
    /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
    (standard_in) 1: syntax error
    install -p -m 644 8852be.ko  /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
    install: cannot stat '8852be.ko': No such file or directory
    make: *** [Makefile:646: install] Error 1
    modprobe: FATAL: Module 8852be not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic
```

It still doesn't work :/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Now you know what is your wireless device. So you can find a solution.

Comment: Ah it finally worked after rebooting! Thank you very much for the link!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)