# Problems with manual installation of a wifi driver for Realtek b852

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 to a new laptop (hp probook 455 g9) and couldn't connect to wifi. Setting says "no adapter found". I found the problem answered here [Network Driver for Realtek 10ec:b852](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852), however I'm having issues with the steps in the accepted answer under that post.

In terminal I wrote:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git bc
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make
```

and after that last step, i received:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
#rm -f .symvers.8852be
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build M=/home/kone/rtl8852be  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: gcc: No such file or directory
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
  CC [M]  /home/kone/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/kone/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1903: /home/kone/rtl8852be] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Error 2
```

Could you please tell me, what's the issue, and how do I make the wifi work?
Thank you for your time.

Edit1: thank you, I was able to continue with `make` and `sudo make install`, but having rebooted, the wifi is still not working. In the linked post, there's another instruction to run `sudo modprobe 8852be`, but I receive this response:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8852be': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: "Operation not permitted" suggests that you should disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI.

Comment: thank you! i thought i disabled it but i failed at the confirmation so it didnt save. thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `build-essential`.

Run

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

and try again `make` command.