# Manually installed wifi driver for Realtek b852 stops working until restarting the computer

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I run Ubuntu 22.04 to a on "hp probook 455 g9". As the wifi wasn't working at first, 7 months ago I asked how to install the wifi driver in the first place, here: [Problems with manual installation of a wifi driver for Realtek b852](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448670/problems-with-manual-installation-of-a-wifi-driver-for-realtek-b852)

Few days ago the wifi stopped registering my wifi, even though it was still working just fine on other devices. When I restarted the computer, it got back on, but soon it stopped working again, so now I'm on 20+ restarts a day.

When restarting, this shows up, [image]

I was suggested to look at this post [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547)
so I'll just post the information:

"sudo lshw -class network":

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 7c:57:58:21:81:ca
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:56 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fb604000-fb604fff memory:fb600000-fb603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 10:b1:df:6b:09:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:78 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fb500000-fb5fffff
```

"lsusb":

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:5483 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c7e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

"lspci":

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

"rfkill list all"

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any ideas what could help solve this? Thank you for your time!

Edit1:
"sudo dmesg | grep rtw":

```
[    2.090191] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.090342] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.186746] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw89/rtw8852b_fw-1.bin failed with error -2
[    2.189627] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8852b_fw.bin
[    2.189702] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.192418] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.27.32.1, cmd version 0, type 1
[    2.192425] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.27.32.1, cmd version 0, type 3
[    2.192431] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: MAC has already powered on
[    2.515654] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: chip rfe_type is 1
[    3.477824] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Edit2:
As I'm writing this, wifi's stopped showing up again,
[image]

"nmcli device wifi list":

```
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

"sudo dmesg | grep wlp":
doesn't result in anything.

I looked at https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git, and if I'm looking correctly, I have kernel > 6.0.0, so maybe that's the problem? If so, would you please tell me how to uninstall rtl8852be, so I can try the rtw89?

Comment: Please see your dmesg above. You are already using the built-in rtw89 driver. Do I understand that it works sometimes but then stops?

Comment: Yeah, it just stops some time after booting - could be a minute, could be an hour.
(Given the fact that the symptoms remain the same, i was under the impression that i didn't manage to install rtw89, sorry for the confusion.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the subject of a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-6.1/+bug/2017277

Let’s try the suggested fix, amended slightly.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtw89.conf
```

Add a single new line:

```
options rtw89_pci disable_clkreq=y disable_aspm_l1=y disable_aspm_l1ss=y
```

Proofread carefully. Save (Ctl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did what you suggested (hopefully correctly), but sadly the wifi stopped working again.

Comment: Are there any interesting clues? Please edit your question to include the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep rtw`

Comment: Looks perfect to me. Does it see networks? `nmcli device wifi list` No need to post the whole list; just tell us if networks are seen. Are there clues here? `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`