# How do I know which modules to blacklist and how to do so correctly, in order to then install a wifi driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless

I run Ubuntu 22.04 to a on "hp probook 455 g9". I want to install a driver for rtl8852be from here https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89, but I'm having troubles understanding how to do so correctly. The repository says:

> You must blacklist the in-tree kernel versions of this driver

and

> If your system has ANY conflicting drivers installed, you must blacklist them as well.

but I don't know how to do it, despite rereading the attached link [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules) and googling around.

I will highly appreciate any support regarding this matter.

---

wireless info:

"sudo lshw -class network":

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 7c:57:58:21:81:ca
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-33-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:56 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fb604000-fb604fff memory:fb600000-fb603fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 10:b1:df:6b:09:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.2.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:78 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fb500000-fb5fffff
```

"lsusb":

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:5483 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c7e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

"lspci":

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

---

edit1:
"lspci -nnk -d ::0280":

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be, rtw_8852be
```

"rfkill list":

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

(My old driver still somewhat works, but it stops working in a matter of minutes after rebooting and is no longer maintained.)

Comment: Post `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` command output

Comment: What results for `rfkill list`

Comment: Your device is supported in Linux 6.2 or later. Did you try just using a default driver?

Comment: When I installed ubuntu, the wifi wasn't even showing up as an option. Then I found out I have to install one manually https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852 .

Comment: @laketax Was it 22.04.3?

Comment: Try `rfkill unblock all` see if it works

Comment: @R A I got this laptop in January and 22.04.3 came out this summer, so I probably had an update since then. Are you implying that the default driver of this version could work with my wifi card now?

Comment: @laketax yes it should

Comment: @Jeremy31 what should it do?

Comment: Your results showed wifi disabled by rfkill, the easy way to unblock is that command

Comment: @R A oh!! how do i get the default driver then?

Comment: It seems `rtw89_8852be` is the default. Further action depends on if it unblocks and works or not

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you, could that be why it regularly stops working until rebooted?

Comment: Stop working might be because of power management, run `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` then reboot

Comment: thank you, i'll try that!!

Comment: sadly it didn't help. should i start a new question then?
(i tried to ask about this issue specifically some weeks ago here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482167/manually-installed-wifi-driver-for-realtek-b852-stops-working-until-restarting-t)

Answer (score 2):

You can blacklist your current driver by executing this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "blacklist rtw89_8852be" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

The command just adds a single line to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file. Removing the last line would revert the changes.

Reboot after making the change.

Comment: thank you so much!