# Wifi Symbol Missing/ Unable to Access Wifi on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 22.10 Lenovo Ideapad1 (Realtek 8852BE) (rtw89)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, realtek, 22.10

Running `lspci -vvv | grep -A 10 -i "Network Controller"` produces:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 4853
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 69
    IOMMU group: 11
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at fd600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
```

Running `neofetch` produces:

```
 .-/+oossssoo+/-.               sean@sean-IdeaPad-1-15ALC7 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 82R4 IdeaPad 1 15ALC7 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 11 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1746 (dpkg), 12 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 42.5 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon G 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Lucienne 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1960MiB / 9819MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Running `sudo lshw -C network` produces:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd600000-fd6fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: be:29:eb:c1:b0:14
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-58-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.238 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Running `lsppci -knn | grep Net -A3` produces:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1aa] (rev 03)
```

On startup, a line of text is displayed reading `rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information`

I have tried deleting and reinstalling to wifi driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 but it didn't work.

I'm thinking maybe my driver is just incompatible with Ubuntu, but I'm not sure.

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

Let me know if you need more info. I will be actively replying to messages here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a good answer here for your chipset https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result from `mokutil --sb-state `please? Your chipset 10ec:b852 is problematic but there are several results here on askubuntu and hopefully one of them will work for you.

Comment: Running `mokutil --sb-state` produces: `SecureBoot disabled` `Platform is in Setup Mode`

Answer (score 0):

After updating from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.10 [the driver mentioned in this question](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) didn't work for me anymore as well.

However, using [this older driver](https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be) fixed the issue.

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git -b dev
cd rtl8852be
make 
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```