# Recent Update (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) Broke wifi drivers (Realtek 8852BE) (rtw89)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, realtek

[Wifi Symbol Missing/ Unable to Access Wifi on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 22.10 Lenovo Ideapad1 (Realtek 8852BE) (rtw89)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452059/wifi-symbol-missing-unable-to-access-wifi-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-and-22-10-lenovo)

^ Above is a previous question I asked that has a lot more information on my drivers. I got my wifi working fine, but after this update, it broke. I am running on the previous update (22.04.1 LTS) because of this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. I will be responding to this actively, so feel free to tell me if more information is needed.

Comment: You don't say if this is a desktop or server install (*they have different kernel stack defaults!*), but if desktop (*which changed from 5.15 GA kernel to 5.19 from 22.10 at 22.04.2*) have you considered switching to use the GA kernel stack?   Both kernel stacks can co-exist on the install too (*though some closed-source kernel modules (nvidia etc) can prevent this, but not an issue if using open-source code*)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  If you're using 22.04.2 but use a 5.15 kernel does it work?  Is it you have issues with 5.19 kernel only? not the 22.04.2?

Comment: I will agree with @guiverc here.  Recently the update on my systems with the 5.19 kernel it broke my Realtek drivers.  I had to download a new one to the 8.051.02 or roll back to the 8.049.02 driver in order for it to work with the 5.19 Kernel.  I did actually find that just going back to the 5.15 Kernel works great.  Plus, if you are using Ubuntu Pro, canonical-livepatch doesn't support the 5.19 kernel at this time so you might miss on important patches.

Comment: @guiverc i'll confirm this is a desktop install, yes. I am not sure what what you said meant, so I'll do some reading. Thank you. I'll give updates if needed.

Comment: @guiverc yeah im not sure what any of what you said means. what are you suggesting I do to fix this issue? do I have to stay on this update of ubuntu until i find working drivers?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS users have two kernel stack choices; the installation media you use sets the default.. If you use (*by choice either post install or by using an ISO/installation media that installs that kernel stack*) the GA stack, you're still using the 5.15 kernel at 22.04, 22.04.1..... even 22.04.5 in ~August/2024 when that's released..  If using HWE then at 22.04.2 you use the 5.19 kernel from 22.10, at 22.04.3 you'll use the 6.0 kernel from 23.04 etc...  ie. my suggestion was to switch/use the GA kernel stack. Both stacks can co-exist on an install too (except if using some 3rd party drivers)

Comment: The wiki page tells you how to install the other stack, mentions you should test it out before you remove the *unwanted* stack (*you need never do this though to keep both stack choices... so you can try 5.19 as upgrades appear to see if your problem is resolved after noticing upgrades, if it's not just reboot & use 5.15*) etc..   If you get warned both stacks can't exist (*due to nvidia kernel modules etc*) then this answer maybe less valuable - your decision..  I provided what I'd likely do (*my thoughts*) given what you asked in your question.

Comment: @guiverc alright i'll try it out later today. and no, i dont have any nvidia hardware on this laptop.