# firmware question during install + no wifi

Tags: wireless, secure-boot, firmware

When installing ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a low-end Lenovo, it asked me about installing third-party firmware/software for wifi etc. I of course said yes, and entered in a password for secureboot where prompted. When I rebooted I was met with a blue screen detailing MOK stuff which I muddled through (I was not expecting it and I don't know if I did the right thing I stepped through the middle option).

Next when I booted into the OS for the first time it does not recognize my wifi card. There are no familiar options to join a network and `nmcli dev ...` only lists the lo device.

I feel that these two things must be related somehow.

Diagnostics:

`sudo lsmod | grep wi`

and

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

reveals no results. Other diagnostics:

```
$ mokutil --sb
SecureBoot enabled
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15d8] (rev cd)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 5762
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56ff IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:55a7 SanDisk Corp. Infinitive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$
```

---

What do I do now?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: My kernel version is  `5.19.0-38-generic`

Comment: Info like your first comment needs to be added into the body of the question with edit. Not as a comment.

Comment: Where the heck are you reading this?? That is not the README at the HRex39 git repo in the link I gave.

Comment: The Hrex39 repo is archived, read only and asks to use a different repo, which is https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 which has the admonishment. Are you suggesting that I use an "obsolete" repo anyways?