# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and kernel module 6.5.0-25-generic does not connect to any wifi network

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I have linux ubuntu installed on my Lenovo Ideapad3, with Realtek network adapter. I connect to any wifi, since last Thursday. I tried as written in many blogs, one of them works. Which was to switch 6.5.0-21-generic version of kernel when booting my laptop. That way it only connects to old router which is 2.4Ghz.
As I understood while reading all these days many articles, I turned off my Tp link modem Archer C6 separately for 2.4 Ghz and 5Ghz, changed to 802.11n but does not work anyway.
I blacklisted kernel drivers in modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and then even bring back balcklisted module. Cannot go any further, would appreciate any assistance.

`https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zj5Zm3Prt4/`

```
$ lsmod | grep rtw_8852be
rtw_8852be             12288  0
rtw_8852b             409600  1 rtw_8852be
rtw89pci               94208  1 rtw_8852be


$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-19 23:47:45 +04; 25min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 854 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 16482)
     Memory: 11.7M
        CPU: 977ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─854 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Mar 20 00:10:07 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879007.7888] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: >
Mar 20 00:10:17 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879017.9037] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> sca>
Mar 20 00:10:17 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879017.9037] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: >
Mar 20 00:10:19 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <warn>  [1710879019.0586] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, f>
Mar 20 00:10:19 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879019.0587] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-no>
Mar 20 00:10:19 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879019.0590] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 20 00:10:19 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <warn>  [1710879019.0592] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'TP-LINK_54EA>
Mar 20 00:10:19 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879019.0594] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'n>
Mar 20 00:10:21 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879021.4152] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconn>
Mar 20 00:10:21 administrator-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1710879021.4153] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: >


$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6a:dd:78:a4:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$ nmcli device status
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp2s0          wifi      disconnected  --         
p2p-dev-wlp2s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --    


$ lsmod | grep rtw
rtw_8852be             12288  0
rtw_8852b             409600  1 rtw_8852be
rtw89pci               94208  1 rtw_8852be
rtw89core             880640  2 rtw89pci,rtw_8852b
mac80211             1720320  2 rtw89pci,rtw89core
cfg80211             1318912  3 rtw89core,mac80211,rtw_8852b


$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


~$ lspci -nnk -d ::0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be, rtw_8852be
```

Comment: Unfortunately nope. It only gives in detail what information I need to give not the solution

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450 for another user with the exact same wifi hardware `[10ec:b852]`, and how they solved it.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading it already, I dont get what is exactly rtw89_8852be, and rtw_8852be, exacty? Are they both modules?