# wifi adaptor not found - realtek RTL8852BE in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, realtek

This is a follow up to what was discussed here:
[wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04)
I'm using a laptop with the same wifi card (Lenovo Ideapad 5 (15",7)), with ubuntu running in dual boot alongside windows 11.
I have followed the steps given by @chili555 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz 
sudo apt purge rtw89-dkms 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git bc
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make
```

only up until when I try `make`, where I get the following error: https://pastebin.com/fvBiZmGH
What should I do now? I should note aswell I am a complete beginner with linux, thank you

Comment: Run `sudo apt install build-essential` and try again.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc` is not installed.

Run `sudo apt install build-essential` and run again `make`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and a different article in askubuntu solved it.
Purchased two laptops, HP ProBook 455 G9, and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTSC on mine.  Everything worked great (bluetooth, screen, touchpad) except the WiFi card was not detected.  The other ProBook 455 G9 with Windows has the network adapter as Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

restart..
The post that helped me:
[How to get Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi card to work on my new laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379716/how-to-get-realtek-rtl8852ae-wifi-card-to-work-on-my-new-laptop/1379800#1379800?newreg=2019ef78344742f2aee2bb4face16edb)