# wifi adaptor not found - realtek RTL8852BE in ubuntu 22.04 on HP pavalion

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, realtek

I have dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 with windows 11 freshly installed but my Wifi is not working. It states that "Wi-Fi adapter not found". The card is an Realtek RTL8852BE.my laptop is hp pavalion 14-ec1 with processor AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics .
when I try to solve with answers of similar questions it shows errors like this,[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xscOQ.jpg)

Is there any way to solve this problem without using internet in ubuntu?

Comment: If you were following this https://askubuntu.com/q/1434945/1210606 then obviously you don't need to remove (-r) a PPA you didn't add. Make sure to start with the answer then follow from `sudo apt install git bc` on. It's always a good idea to understand what the commands do instead of blindly following a specific question that ISN'T applicable to your situation because the user did something before and you didn't. As such a significant part of the question deals with reversing what they did.

Comment: And no, you NEED internet, at least a temporary internet connection. You can use USB tethering from your phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04) Investigate before asking